# How to use ImageNet Database in Matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, classification, object-recognition, machine-learning

How to use ImageNet Database in Matlab for object classification or recognition? I didn't find any tutorial which could practically tell me how to train images on ImageNet database and classify the objects.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! We've closed this question because there are any number of ways to do what you're asking, but we'd need more details to be able to help in any but a [LMGTFY](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=How+to+use+ImageNet+Database+in+Matlab&gws_rd=ssl) sense.

Comment: This question is very broad. Just add deep learning / convolutional networks so that it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MatConvNet](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/). They have samples for image-net classification, such as [this](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/pretrained/). Pre-trained models already exist. You could also train on your own.

1. Check `cnn_imagenet` function in MatConvNet. You will find it useful.
2. There are tutorials. For example [this one](http://clojurehackers.com/p/quantombone/matconvnet).

Comment: Your answer is somehow useful. But i want to use Stanford's ImageNet Database, the largest annotated image dataset.

Comment: It could work on this dataset. I updated my answer.